# Exaggerated Distribution on Sampling from a Density Estimator

Tags: sampling, histogram, density-estimation

I'm training a [NADE](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v15/larochelle11a/larochelle11a.pdf) on a dataset and then sampling from it as described in the paper. My (binary) feature vector that represents each point in the dataset contains a concatenation of various binary one-hot sub-vectors, each of which represents one quantity of interest. Once I get the samples, I compute some basic occurrence statistics (histograms) over the various subvectors to see whether they match-up with the dataset. I observe plots such as those below:

[image: Histogram over the possible values of the quantity represented by one of the subvectors.]

[image: Histogram over the possible values of the quantity represented by another subvector.]

[image: Histogram over the possible values of the quantity represented by yet another subvector.]

So, for instance in the *dataset* subplot of the first plot above, the first and third (out of 13) values assumed by the quantity represented by the first subvector occur roughly 5000 times each in the dataset.

One can see that while the relative proportions of the values of the values of each of the quantities seem to be well-modelled, the absolute difference between the heights of the bars is very exaggerated. I have sampled a lot more points than the size of the dataset itself, however, I don't think this is the reason for the exaggeration. Ignoring the missing bins in the last histogram, could someone explain what this exaggerated difference in values of the generated data could be a symptom of?

Comment: Could you give us more details?

Comment: I added some more information about the feature vector and some more details to understand the plots. Could you tell me what in particular you think might help? I'd be happy to include those details as well.